# NUnit recognizes all tests but does not run all

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nunit

I'm using NUnit 3.0.1 and Visual Studio 2015, and can confirm that my issue does not occur in Visual Studio 2013.

After cleaning and building the solution, the Test Explorer shows there are 100 tests not yet run. But when I click "Run All" in the Test Explorer, only ~20% of the unit tests run, the rest stay greyed out and still are labeled as not yet run.

However if I clean and build again, it again shows 100 tests not yet run, but if I right click the "Not Run Tests" group and selected "Run Selected Tests", it will correctly run all the tests.

My tests are currently contained in a `[TestFixture]` and it appears that only 2 out of 10 of my `[TestCaseSource]`s are being run.

Comment: Had the same issue. "Run All" worked fine until I added a new test and then only a few would run. Probably a bug in the new NUnit runner.

Comment: I've got the same issue with NUnit 2.6.4 and Visual Studio 2013.